# Create e-shop grid with pure css

Tags: html, css, positioning, grid-layout

I am creating eshop which has products aligned in table-grid. I want price and buy-now button to be displayed at bottom of table row but I dont know how to acomplish it. My table consists of table rows. Div containing products are in these rows. I think that the best solution would be to expand div to 100% height of table row and then set div (with price and buy-now button) to vertical align bottom. But I dont know how it works.

Here is live example for better understanding:

http://autoflex.zone42.sk/kategoria-produktu/znacky/alfa-romeo/

I know that this can easily be accomplished with javascript but I dont want to use javascript. So is there any other way to do it with css only?

Thanks in forward

Comment: That site is responsive. I wouldn't use `<table>` if you want responsive. Use only `<div>`'s with a CSS grid setup. grid.css would be a good template to start with.

Comment: yes that site is responsive but I've thought that I cant accomplish it without table. So you are suggesting this http://960.gs/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [responsivegridsystem](http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/) You would put all div items relating to each product within each grid box.

**EDITED**

Using the weblink content as an example, you would set a given height to the description panel. That way all the prices would line up eg:

```
div.product-desc {
    height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: it doesnt solve problem with height and I already have bootstrap included and it has some sort of grid system but it also doesnt solve height problems. Take a better look at page I have provided. I need all prices to be aligned in same height so they would look like they are in one row.

Comment: ok I have tried to not use fixed height but it looks like I will be forced to use it